# Backbone js button click event not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, backbone.js

I have an ajax function on the initialize of the main router that seems to hinder the event of my signin button in `signin.js`. When I click the signin button, it doesn't perform its function, instead the browser places the inputs on the URL, (i.e. username and password).
But when I remove the ajax function on the initialize, I can successfully log in.

I've included some of the codes I'm working on. Thanks

main.js

```
initialize: function(){
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "something here",
      contentType: "application/json",
      headers: {
          'someVar': something here
      },
      statusCode: {
          404: function() {
              console.log('404: logged out');
              if (!this.loginView) {
                  this.loginView = new LoginView();
              }
              $('.pagewrap').html(this.loginView.el);
          },
          200: function() {
              console.log('200');
              if (!this.homeView) {
                  this.homeView = new HomeView();
              }
              $('.pagewrap').html(this.homeView.el);
          }
      }
    });
  // return false;         
},
```

signin.js

```
var SigninView = Backbone.View.extend ({
    el: '#signin-container',
    events: {
        "click #btn-signin" : "submit"
    },
    submit: function () {
        console.log('signin');
        $.ajax({ ... });
        return false;
    }
});
var toSignin = new SigninView();
window.anotherSigninView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {},
    render: function() {}
});
```

home.js

```
window.HomeView = Backbone.View.extend ({
    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
        $(this.el).html( this.template() );
        return this;
    }
});
```

some html

```
<form id="signin-container">
<table id="tbl-signin">
    <tr>
        <td><div class="input-box"><input class="input-text" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"></div></td>
        <td><div class="input-box"><input class="input-text" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"></div></td>
        <td><input id="btn-signin" class="button" value="Sign In"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="opt"><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="rememberMe" value="true"><label class="opt-signin">Remember Me?</label></td>
        <td class="opt"><a class="opt-signin" href="#">Forgot Password?</a></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
 </table>
 </form>
```

Comment: Can you include your HomeView code ? And where did you instantiate the SigninView ?

Comment: I've added the `homeView` nothing fancy though. `var signinView = new SigninView();` I placed it at the bottom of signin.js, if that's what you're asking

Comment: If you delete the two lines of your ajax function : $('.pagewrap').html( ... ; it still works ?

Comment: well, it will lose its purpose and I wouldn't be able to test the signin button as it is in the `homeView`

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were using <a /> links. My answer prevents links defaults behavior.

Comment: you say that you wouldn't be able to test the signin button as it is in the homeView, so how did you test your code when you commented out the initialize function ?

Comment: oh right, what was I saying, it should be the `signout` button that is in the `homeView`, sorry about that

Comment: Are you sure that when you click the '<input id="btn-signin" ...' button the browser places the inputs on the URL ! I think that I'm missing something.

Comment: not when I remove the `type="submit"`, I removed it because I've created an event of `#btn-signin` in my view that sends an ajax request.

Comment: So you have resolved your problem or not yet ?

Comment: Not yet. I'm working with the `initialize` commented out so that I can sign in and out of my app, but when I sign out, `#btn-signin` doesn't seem to work unless I refresh the page, why do you think that is ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I figured out what's your problem :)

Here is an example that resumes your code [jsfiddle.net/26xf4/6](http://jsfiddle.net/26xf4/6). The problem is that you don't call `new SigninView()`; (instantiate the view) hence its events are never bound.

So, in this example try to uncomment the ligne 43 and your code will work as expected, because when you instantiate a View `(new SigninView())` its constructor calls the `delegateEvents()` function (you don't see this in your code, it's in the backbone.js) enabling the events you declare in your view :

```
events: {
    "click #btn-signin" : "submit"
},
```

Comment: could you please explain this ?

Comment: even though I don't have a `render` function in my `signinView` ?

Comment: Tried `new SigninView().render();` it's working now thanks! Could you please explain why this is happening ?

Comment: You don't need to call `render` if you want, I updated my answer.

Comment: I see, I just need to instantiate them. But at the bottom of my `signin.js` I've created a `var toSignin = new SigninView();` wouldn't  it be the same as instantiating `SigninView`?

Comment: but it executes the function at the further bottom of it

Comment: Can you update the example to reflect what your code looks like.

Comment: Are you sure that your signin.js file is loaded somewhere, try to add an `alert('I am loaded');` (or console.log()) before the `var toSignin = new SigninView();` to see if this code is reached

Comment: So there is another view pointing to the same el `#signin-container` and it's instantiated after your `SigninView` view, thus the first view's events binding are lost.

Comment: that's quite possible based on how I created my app, I got 2 views for supposedly 1 page, I did that because I have a template which uses the `el` and I placed my events on a different view so that their `el` won't have a conflict, you think that's what causes the problem? I'm still new to backbone and I haven't really grasped how to work around this `el`

Comment: necessarily, if you have two views that point to the same el and both must be rendered, so you have to merge them in a single view.

Comment: I can't merge them because their `el` are different from each other, ` is to render the template which uses `<div>` for its `el` while I use the other `el` for the `<form>`

Comment: Is one `el` inside the other? If that's the case so you have to merge the views.

Comment: No because it causes some errors that why I placed them separately. ie  `SigninView` which renders the template and the other `toSigninView` where the events are placed

Comment: You have to merge the two views, nothing else to say :)

Comment: This is what I get when I merge them `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'template' `

Comment: Can you update the jsfiddle with your merged view and post it here ?

Comment: It's a bit messy now sorry about that, the `signin.js` is pretty much the same with the `edit.js`. I've also added `utils.js` which I used for the templates.

Comment: I propose to close this question (accept the answer) and ask another one with your new problem, because this one has become so big that it's no more benefic for future users to find what they need.

Comment: You are welcome, let me know about your new question.

Comment: I've created http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21439137/backbonejs-usage-of-el, I think the problem is with the elements, apparently I still haven't got used to using `el`

Answer (score 3):

You need to prevent the default behaviour of the `submit` button in your `click` handler. You can do this like so:

```
var SigninView = Backbone.View.extend ({
    el: '#signin-container',
    events: {
        "click #btn-signin" : "submit"
    },
    submit: function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log('signin');
        $.ajax({ ... });
    }
});
```

Alternatively, you might consider using the html `button` element which won't attempt to submit the form it's associated with.

Comment: actually I do have `return false;` right after the ajax function. But still it doesn't do `console.log('signin');`

Comment: the result will be the same, the problem is within the backbone not in the html

Comment: I disagree. The submit button is trying to submit the form which is why you see the form values in the URL. Try my updated answer.

Comment: oh, right, that's one thing. But my working ajax function (if the initialize is commented out) is properly working where it doesn't post the input on the URL

Comment: Your initialize function references a LoginView but the view you've posted is called SigninView. Could this be an issue?

Comment: I doubt it, the `LoginView` is for template rendering while the `SigninView` is where I put the functionality, both works fine without the ajax function in initialize, I'm sorry about that I'm still new to Backbone that's why I still can't properly create my views.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your HTML mockup, my best guess is that you are catching the incorrect event here. If you are submitting a form, you should catch `submit form` event not `click #some-button`. Because even if you catch `click` event of button inside a form and return false, the form will be still submitted because those are 2 different events

Comment: I tried changing it to `submit #buttonName` it's still the same

Comment: Could you put your HTML here as well? It might help

Comment: And btw, you need to listen to the `form` itself, as in `submit #form-id` not `submit #buttonName`

Comment: Then you need to change `"click #btn-signin" : "submit"` to `"submit #signin-containe" : "submit"`

Comment: Even though I don't have `type="submit"` in my `input` tag ?

Comment: I've tried putting `type="submit"` in the input tag and changed the events, still it wasn't firing up the sign in instead it's doing the plain html submit

Comment: As I remember the default behavior of buttons is to submit the form (if it is placed inside one). And since you are not be able to catch the `submit` event, I think you might have some errors during the submission which cause the handler code fail to execute

Comment: I don't use `<button>` tag instead I use `<input>