# Backbonejs usage of el

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I've created 2 separate views, 1 to render the template and the other one is where I bind the events, then I tried merging them into one in which case it causes an `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'template'`. It renders the template and the events are working as well, but I get the error.

edit.js, this is the combined view, which I think it has something to do with their `el` where the error is coming from

```
window.EditView = Backbone.View.extend ({
    events: {
        "click #btn-save" : "submit"
    },
    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
        $(this.el).html(this.template());
        return this;
    },
    submit: function () {
        console.log('editing');
        $.ajax({ ... });
        return false;
    }
});
var editView = new EditView();
```

signin.js, this is the view that I can't merge because of the `el` being used by the ajax call and in `SigninView`'s `$(this.el)` which causes the rendering of the templates faulty

```
window.toSigninView = Backbone.View.extend ({
    el: '#signin-container',
    events: {
        "click #btn-signin" : "submit"
    },
    initialize: function() {
        console.log('Signin View');
    },
    submit: function() {
        $.ajax({ ... });
        return false;
    }
});


var toSignin = new toSigninView();

window.SigninView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
        $(this.el).html(this.template());
        return this;
    }
});
```

and I use utils.js to call my templates

```
window.utils = {
    loadTpl: function(views, callback) {
        var deferreds = [];
        $.each(views, function(index, view) {
            if (window[view]) {
                deferreds.push($.get('templates/' + view + '.html', function(data) {
                    window[view].prototype.template = _.template(data);
                }));
            } else {
                alert(view + " not found");
            }
        });
        $.when.apply(null, deferreds).done(callback);
    }
};
```

In my Router.js, this is how I call the rendering of templates

```
editProfile: function() {
    if (!this.editView) {
        this.editView = new EditView();
    }
    $('#global-container').html(this.editView.el);
},
utils.loadTpl (['SigninView', 'EditView'], 
function() {
    appRouter = new AppRouter();
    Backbone.history.start();

});
```

Comment: `Backbone.View` doesn't have a `template()` method (which is what you're trying to call with `this.template()`. Do you mean to use `_.template()` instead? I think you think `this === window` in a Backbone method context, which it doesn't. It's unclear why you've included `window.utils` in your question as you don't seem to ever be using it in your other code

Comment: I've added the router where I call `utils.js`

Comment: oh sorry, that's a typo in my question. I've updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that I figured out your problem.

First merge your views and delete the line `var toSignin = new toSigninView();`

Second modify your utils.js code like this :

```
window[view].prototype.template = _.template(data);
new window[view]();
```

Comment: Does this mean that all the instances of `var toSignin = new toSigninView();` for the other views should be removed as well?

Comment: Also do I still need to instantiate the views with `new viewName();` like before ?

Comment: Yes you should remove all the instances you mentioned and you don't need any more to instantiate the views, because the `loadTpl` would do it for you. But I don't think that the way you are using Backbone is optimal, try to take a look at this tutorial http://www.jboss.org/jdf/examples/ticket-monster/tutorial/UserFrontEnd/

Comment: I see, by the way [this](https://github.com/ccoenraets/nodecellar) is where I got the rendering of templates it's because I tried to avoid the use of `Require.js`. That's a good reference and they're working properly now, thanks a lot!